# What is a good way to send large data sets to a client through API requests?

Tags: sql-server, rest, azure

A client's system will connect to our system via an API for a data pull.  For now this data will be stored in a data mart, and say 50,000 records per request.

I would like to know the most efficient way of delivering the payload which originates in a SQL Azure database.

The API request will be a RESTful.  After the request is received, I was thinking that the payload would be retrieved from the database, converted to JSON, and GZIP encoded/transferred over HTTP back to the client.

I'm concerned about processing this may take with many clients connected pulling a lot of data.

Would it be best to just return the straight results in clear text to the client?

Suggestions welcome.

**-- UPDATE --**

To clarify, this is not a web client that is connecting.  The connection is made by another application to receive a one-time, daily data dump, so no pagination.

The data consists primarily of text with one binary field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment, so ...

The best method may well be one of those "it depends" answers.

Is the just the database on azure, or is your whole entire hosting on azure. Never did any production on Azure myself.

What are you trying to optimize for -- total round response time, total server CPU time, or perhaps sometime else?

For example, if you database server is azure and but but you web server is local perhaps you can simply optimize the database request and depend on scaling via multiple web servers if needed.

If data the changes with each request, you should never compress it if you are trying to optimize server CPU load, but you should compress it if you are trying to optimize bandwidth usage -- either can be your bottleneck / expensive resource.

For 50K records, even JSON might be a bit verbose. If you data is a single table, you might have significant data savings by using something like CSV (including the 1st row as a record header for a sanity check if nothing else). If your result is a result of joining multiple table, i.e., hierarchical, using JSON would be recommended simply to avoid the complexity of rolling your own heirarchical representation.

Are you using a SSL or your webserver, if so SSL could be your bottleneck (unless this is handled via other hardware)

What is the nature of the data you are sending? Is is mostly text, numbers, images? Text usually compress well, numbers less so, and images poorly (usually). Since you suggest JSON, I would expect that you have little if any binary data though.

If compressing JSON, it can be a very efficient format since the repeated field name mostly compress out of your result. XML likewise (but less so this the tags come in pairs)

ADDED

If you know what the client will be fetching before hand and can prepare the packet data in  advance, by all means do so (unless storing the prepared data is an issue). You could run this at off peak hours, create it as a static .gz file and let IIS serve it directly when needed. Your API could simply be in 2 parts 1) retrieve a list of static .gz files available to the client 2) Confirm processing of said files so you can delete them.

Presumably you know that JSON & XML are not as fragile as CSV, i.e., added or deleting fields from your API is usually simple. So, if you can compress the files, you should definitely use JSON or XML -- XML is easier for some clients to parse, and to be honest if you use the Json.NET or similar tools you can generate either one from the same set of definitions and information, so it is nice to be flexible. Personally, I like Json.NET quite a lot, simple and fast.

Comment: We are planning to host the entire environment in Azure - SQL Azure and Web Role to manage the API requests.  If the client's data set is say, 50,000, would be a good idea to break it up into CSV packages?  Thinking of this, I wonder if we could launch a Worker Role to create the CSV data files, compress them, and store them until the client app connects.  Other thoughts?

Comment: Added response to your comment.

Answer (score 4):

First of all : do not optimize prematurely! that means : dont sacrifice simplicity and maintainability of your code for gain you dont event know.

Lets see. 50000 records does not really say anything without specifying size of the record. I would advise you start from basic implementation and optimize when needed. So try this

1. Implement simple JSON response with that 50000 records, and try to call it from consumer app. Measure size of data and response time - evaluate carefully, if this is really a problem for once a day operation
2. If yes, turn on compression for that JSON response - this is usually HUGE change with JSON because of lots of repetitive text. One tip here: set content type header to "application/javascript" - Azure have dynamic compression enabled by default for this content type. Again - try it, evaluate if size of data or reponse time is problem
3. If it is still problem, maybe it is time for some serialization optimization after all, but i would strogly recommend something standard and proved here (no custom CSV mess), for example Google Protocol Buffers : https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Answer (score 1):

Normally what happens with such large requests is pagination, so included in the JSON response is a URL to request the next lot of information.

Now the next question is what is your client? e.g. a Browser or a behind the scenes application.

If it is a browser there are limitations as shown here:
http://www.ziggytech.net/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/

If it is an application then your current approach of 50,000 requests in a single JSON call would be acceptable, the only thing you need to watch here is the load on the DB pulling the records, especially if you have many clients.

Comment: I updated the question for better clarity.  Yes this is a case where there is no pagination, and a large amount of data would be transmitted to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a third-party library, you can try [Heavy-HTTP](https://github.com/Heavy-HTTP) which solves this problem out of the box. (I'm the author of the library)